# Variable access into a javascript array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this array:

[image]

And i am not be able to access to the true or false having the first parameter (cs_test_......) stored in a variable named value.id

How can I access to the true or false only knowing the first part? cs_test_......

Comment: `{"Surname": Miky}` is not a valid object but `{Surname: "Miky"}`. You can do something like this: `const obj = {Surname: "Miky"}; const result = JSON.stringify(obj).replace(/"([^"]+)"/,"$1")`. It will return `{Surname:"Miky"}`
`

Comment: I have edited the question to clarify it

Comment: you should use raw text instead of an image for the input

Comment: I think you should refactor this. There must be some other easier way to do what you want to achieve

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume you loop through your array, and have a value item.

Then, you loop through the object's properties this way.

```
for (var key of Object.keys(item)) {

    if ( key.toString().startsWith("cs_test_"))
    {
        console.log(key + " -> " + item[key])
    }
}
```

In this case, we're logging the value out, with the key name.